# Trigger event in ViewModel when ListBoxItem has hover over

Tags: wpf, binding, listbox, viewmodel, listboxitem

### Issue

---

I have a *Listbox* that displays a list of images. I want to be able to hover over an image and for it to display the image in a bigger size. I am able to get the hover effect and for it to display some text i entered, but i need the image to change for different *ListBoxItems*.

### Code

---

Here is the code I have used to get the hover effects:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>                    
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,0,5,5" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="140"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/>  
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Control.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding IMAGEHERE}"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="#d64b36" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

So as you can see I have the tooltip but i need to image to be bound to the value from the ViewModel.

If an event in my ViewModel could get triggered when I hovered over a ListBoxItem it should solve my issue.

Comment: `<Setter Property="ToolTip">
      <Setter.Value>
             <Image Source="{Binding Imagepath}" />
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>`

Comment: @Gopichandar How do i trigger a method in my ViewModel to set the imagepath?

Comment: There should be a Property called `Imagepath` in your VM that should hold the path of the image.

Comment: @Gopichandar But each ListBoxItem has a different image so the property will need to change depending on the image.

Comment: Of course it should.  You will have the `List<items>` and each `item` should contain `Imagepath`

Comment: @Gopichandar Can you write an example i think i am getting confused.

Comment: @Gopichandar Ahh! I understand. It works now :)

Comment: See my answer below. .Oh, you got it. .  Great!

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it worked for you.  Thanks and have a nice day. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can set the `ToolTip` with the `Image` control.

```
 <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="Control.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Control.ToolTip">
            <Setter.Value> 
                  <Image Source="{Binding Imagepath}" /> 
            </Setter.Value>
       </Setter>
    </Trigger>
 </Style.Triggers>
```

then, you can pass the source as `Imagepath` property from your ViewModel.  I haven't tested this.